failed compiling with xcodebuild, swift package manager, iOS 17 and swift-confidential
My app compiles, validates and stores correctly from Xcode IDE using the library swift-confidential (a tool for obfuscating Swift literals).
But I cannot use Xcode on my osx server so I need to use xcodebuild, where I have always successfully compiled my app with my environment variables...
I've installed both libraries with SPM both to 0.3.0 release. All works great on Xcode IDE.
My commands on prompt:
# remove all old settings
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
# skip plugin SDK validation requirement
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESkipMacroFingerprintValidation -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESkipPackagePluginFingerprintValidatation -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESkipPackagePluginValidation -bool YES

xcodebuild -workspace "$PROJECT_PATH" -scheme "MYAPP" -skipPackagePluginValidation -configuration 
'Release' DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="$DEVELOPER_TEAM" PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$COMPOSE_PROFILE  
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$CERT_ID_DISTRIBUTION" build

where $PROJECT_PATH and the other environmental variables are correctly setted.
This is the error:
/Users/cm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-aiforaavtwmmlzduwibsbgvwnosl/SourcePackages/checkouts/
swift-confidential-plugin/Package.swift: error: Bundle identifier is missing. Confidential doesn't have a 
bundle identifier. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor. (in target 
'Confidential' from project 'swift-confidential-plugin')
** BUILD FAILED **

[1;31m Error: ATTENZIONE: Il comando [xcodebuild -workspace "MYAPP.xcworkspace" -scheme "MYAPP" build] ha restituito il seguente Error Code [65] [0m
[[1;31mERROR[m] Command execution failed.

It seems that xcodebuild would not skip checking the plugin library, as the commands I set before and during the build launch via the -skipPackagePluginValidation command tell it to do.
What other inline command should I add to avoid checking this spm plugin?

You issue securevale/swift-confidential issue 3 has now (June 2024) been closed as "wontfix".
Michał Gutowski adds in the issue:

I successfully reproduced your issue with Xcode 15.4 (15F31d).
Based on my testing, it looks like this is a bug in xcodebuild — when passing PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER and CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY build settings to xcodebuild, it applies them to every target (incl. SwiftPM plugin targets that do not support code signing), resulting in code signing failure(s).
You can also test this with SwiftLintBuildToolPlugin and you will get the same result.
However, if you navigate in Xcode to your target's Signing & Capabilities settings, manually select the provisioning profile for Release builds and run xcodebuild -workspace "MyApp.xcworkspace" -scheme "MyApp" -configuration Release -skipPackagePluginValidation clean build, then the build will succeed.
Hopefully, they will fix it someday (worth retesting with Xcode 16 RC once it's available).
If your use case is to build the project and/or run automated tests as part of your CI pipeline, then you can work around this issue by completely disabling the code signing with CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO build setting.
Otherwise, to package the app for distribution, you may also archive the project with that same build setting and only code sign it when exporting the archive to an IPA file.
Finally, as a side note, setting defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESkipPackagePluginFingerprintValidatation -bool YES has the same effect as passing -skipPackagePluginValidation, so you only need one of the two. Also, you should use PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER instead of PROVISIONING_PROFILE, as the latter is deprecated.

